# combination of jax-rs (rest api) and websockets - where to put common initialization

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, initialization, jax-rs

I am developing a project which involves JAX-RS (for REST API) and Websocket (for notifications). The project will be deployed as a WAR into a application server.

For JAX-RS, I do the following:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyApplicationREST extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplicationREST() {
        ... initialization here ...
    }
}
```

For Websockets, I do the following:

```
public class MyApplicationWebsockets implements ServerApplicationConfig {
    ... callbacks for discovery of endpoints here ...
}
```

Both classes are perfectly picked up by the application server (Tomcat in my case) when the WAR is deployed and work fine in vacuum.

However, in both classes, I need a reference to a command instance (being the database connection in this case, but it can be anything). I cannot instantiate it in one of the two classes above (and use it in the other), as there is no guarantee of the initialization order of the two classes.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

### Initialization

(1) Create a class that implements [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html).

(2) Write your initialization code in [contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized-javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent-) method.

```java
public class MyContextListener implements ServletContextListener
{
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent context)
    {
        // Your initialization code here.
    }


    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent context)
    {
        // Your finalization code here.
    }
}
```

(3) Register the class as a listener in `web.xml`.

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.example.MyContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

### Shared Instance

Regarding a shared instance, *singleton pattern* is one of possible means to achieve it.

```java
public class DB
{
    private static final DB sInstance = new DB();

    // Private constructor to prevent DB instances from being created by others.
    private DB()
    {
    }

    // Get the singleton instance.
    public static DB getInstance()
    {
        return sInstance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This allows me indeed to instantiate everything beforehore. But how do I get a reference to it in the two classes from the original question? Should I make `public static` field(s)?

Comment: Thanks. Interesting, Is it also possible to inject the `DB` instance into the two bootstrap classes (see original question) with @Inject?